# How to remove leading spaces from strings in a dataseries/list?

Tags: string, pandas, list, dataframe, split

I am doing a network analysis via networks and noticed that some of the nodes are being treated differently just because they have extra spaces (leading).

I tried to remove the spaces using the following codes but I cannot seem to make the output become strings again.

```
rhedge = pd.read_csv(r"final.edge.csv")
rhedge

_________________
 source | to
 niala  | Sana, Sana
 Wacko  | Ana, Aisa

rhedge['to'][1]
'Sana, Sana'

rhedge['splitted_users2'] = rhedge['to'].apply(lambda x:x.split(','))

#I need to split them so they will be included as different nodes
```

#### The problem is with the next code

```
rhedge['splitted_users2'][1]
['Sana', ' Sana']
```

#### As you can see the second Sana has a leading space.

#### I tried to do this:

```
split_users = []

for i in split:
    row = [x.strip() for x in i]
    split_users.append(row)

pd.Series(split_users)
```

But when I am trying to split them by "," again, it won't allow me because the dataset is now  list. I believe that splitting them would make networks treat them as one node as opposed to creating a different node for one with a leading space.

THANK YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Changing the `lambda` expression

```py
import pandas pd

# dataframe creation
df = pd.DataFrame({'source': ['niala', 'Wacko'], 'to': ['Sana, Sana', 'Ana, Aisa']})

# split and strip with a list comprehension
df['splitted_users2'] = df['to'].apply(lambda x:[y.strip() for y in x.split(',')])

print(df['splitted_users2'][0])

>>> ['Sana', 'Sana']
```

### Alternatively

#### Option 1

- Split on `', '` instead of `','`

```py
df['to'] = df['to'].str.split(', ')
```

#### Option 2

- Replace `' '` with `''` and then split on `','`
- This has the benefit of removing any whitespace around either name (e.g. `['    Sana,    Sana', '   Ana,    Aisa']`)

```py
df['to'] = df['to'].str.replace(' ', '').str.split(',')
```

- If you want the names split into separate columns, see [SO: Pandas split column of lists into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns)